# how to use template.find() to get the checkbox checked or not?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a template that have a checkbox input:

If I use this html

```
 <label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" name="apPartTime"  
      checked="{{isWorkChecked 'isPartTime'}}">Part Time
</label>
```

and
    `let isPartTime = $('[name=apPartTime]').is(':checked');`

I can get true or false back, but if I want to use javascript only, how can I get the boolean value?

If the html like this

```
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox"  id ="apFullTime" 
      checked="{{isWorkChecked 'apFullTime'}}">Full Time
</label>
```

and I want to get this checkbox is checked or not

I tried

```
let isFullTime = template.find('#apFullTime').value;
let isFullTime = template.find('#apFullTime');
```

None is worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wrap your checkbox in a form, you could retrieve the value by accessing `event.target.myId.checked`.

For example:

```
<template name="myTemplate">
    <form class="my-form">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" id="ap-full-time-form">Full Time
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</template>
```

---

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
    'submit .my-form'(event, instance) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let isChecked = event.target["ap-full-time-form"].checked;
        console.log(isChecked);
    }
});
```

---

If you want to register a separate Meteor event for input types, you could access the value directly by using `event.target.checked`.

For instance:

```
<template name="myTemplate">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="ap-full-time-form">Full Time
    </label>
</template>
```

---

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
    'click input'(event, instance) {
        let isChecked = event.target.checked;
        console.log(isChecked);
    }
});
```

---

In addition, you could simply use `instance.find("#myId").checked`:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
    'submit .my-form'(event, instance) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let isChecked = instance.find("#ap-full-time-form").checked;
        console.log(isChecked);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!